# How can I get the group id of a node using tokens?

Tags: organic-groups, tokens

I try to use [node:og_group_ref], but that gives me the group node title and I need the GID, I am sure there should be a way to get it but I haven't found it

Answer (score 0):

In Organic Groups 7.2 the Node idea and Group id are the same. So if you are using views you can do the following:

Add field "Content: Nid" and exclude if from display.
Any field arranged below the above can use [nid] as a rewrite giving you the Group ID.

Does this help?

Comment: Since the question seems to imply the group ID is stored in `og_group_ref`, I believe the author is looking for ID of the group(s) of which the current node is a member. Taking the node ID does not solve it, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `[node:og_group_ref]` token output the numerical ID instead of the group name by setting up the "Token" display mode for your content type and choosing the "Entity id" formatter for that field:

As shown in [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1224702#comment-6704548) in the issue queue:

1. Go to "Structure → Content Types → [your content type] → Manage Display".
2. Click "Custom Display Settings" below the field list, enable the "Token" option and save.
3. Go to the new "Token" display mode in the horizontal tabs on the top.
4. For your`og_group_ref` field, set "Format: Entity id" and save.

Answer (score -1):

Like so:
[node:og-group-ref--og-membership--1:0:id]